# Loading data from one couchbase server to another

Tags: couchbase

I want to import data into my local machine.
is there any way to do it?

thanks,
Michael

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbtransfer_tool.html

Answer (score 1):

[cbtransfer tool](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbtransfer_tool.html) is your friend for this one. As an added benefit, you can also give it regular expressions to only do a subset of data in case you care.